# Issue while archive from terminal

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, archive, xcframework

I am building XCFramework, while archive from terminal facing below issue.

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal arm64
(3 failures)
```

Below script using for archive

```
xcodebuild archive \
 -scheme SampleSDK \
 -archivePath ~/Desktop/SampleSDK-iphonesimulator.xcarchive \
 -sdk iphonesimulator \
 SKIP_INSTALL=NO
```

Comment: check this link : [link](https://medium.com/trueengineering/xcode-and-xcframeworks-new-format-of-packing-frameworks-ca15db2381d3)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470694/got-an-archive-failed-when-trying-xcodebuild-archive-in-terminal