# xcodebuild archive failing with SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, xcodebuild, xcframework

I have a framework and it has other frameworks as dependency. I wanted to archive the framework for Device, Simulator to create XCFramework. when i run below command archive is failing with below command.

Command Used:

`xcodebuild archive \ -scheme XXXX \ -sdk iphoneos \ -archivePath "archives/ios_devices.xcarchive" \ BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \ SKIP_INSTALL=NO`

Failing with below error from command line.

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ XXXX (in target 'XXXX' from project 'XXXX')
(1 failure)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. If you are using workspace, you should add this line to your archive building commands.

```
-workspace SampleFramework.xcworkspace \
```

I saw this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66621660/21255381)

============================================

I want include Alamofire to my framework and I want build it as xcframework. So when I build it, I have the same problem which you got.

The things what i tried :

1. include 'VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64" to the iphone simulator archive building command
2. include -destination to the archive building command
3. try the framework's Mach-O Type to dynamic, static library
4. check the framework's build settings. not to include amr64 architecture when it running as phone.

All I did cannot solve the problem. Did you find any solution? Also I'm not good at English. Please excuse me for this.